# want to encrypt password like devise gem and check in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to encrypt password through devise gem manually? is there any gem for this?

Password is coming form web service and i want to encrypt it and check in my db

Answer (score 1):

Devise internally uses Bcrypt gem to do encryption.
[Bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  before_save :encrypt_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Try this.